# SharePoint 2013 App not using site master page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-apps

I've created a simple SharePoint 2013 application and have setup:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
         MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>
```

However, I've a publishing site with a custom master page setup as default and custom.  This master page is now reflected when I go to the application within the site.  Note, this is an Office 365 tenant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to forcibly designate the app#0 webtemplate to be used?
see blogpost:
http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Akhilesh/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=11

This blogpost refers to the following msdn documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179925.aspx#TypesOfSPComponentsInApps